# Pandas - selecionar linhas

Tags: python, pandas

Olá.

Como seleciono uma linha específica num dataframe?

```
df1=pd.read_csv('arquivo1.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', sep=";")
```

Já tentei fazer `df.index[2]`, mas dá erro. O 2 é a linha que eu quero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a propriedade [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Por exemplo, para o seguinte CSV:

```
Year;Make;Model;Description;Price
1997;Ford;E350;"ac, abs, moon";3000.00
1999;Chevy;"Venture ""Extended Edition""";"";4900.00
1999;Chevy;"Venture ""Extended Edition; Very Large""";;5000.00
1996;Jeep;Grand Cherokee;"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded";4799.00
```

O código a seguir imprime o conteúdo todo e depois somente a terceira linha (índice 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('teste.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', sep=";")
print('Tudo:\n', df1)

lin = df1.loc[2]
print('Linha 3:\n', lin)
```

Resultado:

```
>teste.py
Tudo:
    Year   Make                                   Model  \
0  1997   Ford                                    E350
1  1999  Chevy              Venture "Extended Edition"
2  1999  Chevy  Venture "Extended Edition; Very Large"
3  1996   Jeep                          Grand Cherokee

                            Description   Price
0                         ac, abs, moon  3000.0
1                                   NaN  4900.0
2                                   NaN  5000.0
3  MUST SELL!\r\nair, moon roof, loaded  4799.0
Linha 3:
 Year                                             1999
Make                                            Chevy
Model          Venture "Extended Edition; Very Large"
Description                                       NaN
Price                                            5000
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Fonte do CSV de exemplo: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example).